# is there a way to delete a message that has a specific word with a discord bot if the word is in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've tried this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JEWm.png

and I've also tried

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nhLz.png

but it gave me a warning

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include relevant code and errors/warnings in the question as formatted text.  For tips and information on how to ask a question, please see [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an on_message event:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    # replace the 123 for whatever you want:
    if '123' in message.content: 
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send("You can't say that!")

    # you can do this how many times you want
    if '321' in message.content: 
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send("You can't say that!")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add your code instead of a screenshot of it.

> but it gave me a warning

It always helps if you say what "a warning" is, but my guess is that it says that you didn't provide an argument for `startswith()`.

You're using `startswith()` incorrectly: in order to check if a string starts with another string, you're supposed to pass the other string as the **argument** to `startswith()`, not do `startswith() == "123"` which makes no sense. You're comparing a `bool` to a `string`...

```py
# Instead of
>>> "something".startswith() === "so"  # ?
False

# Do
>>> "something".startswith("so")
True
```

To check if something is somewhere in the middle, combine the `in` operator and check if it's not in the beginning with `startswith()`. You should be able to figure that one out on your own - I'm not gonna code it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this

```
b_words = ["Cats", "Dogs"]
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if b_words in message:
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send("Mind your language!")
    return
```

This will check if there is a bad word in the message. If there is, then it will delete that message and send a warning.

According to the code provided by you in your question, it will not check if the word is in the middle of the sentence. It will only check if the sentence starts with it.

**EDIT**

```
b_words = ["Cats", "Dogs"]
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for word in b_words:
        if word.lower() in message.content: #.lower() for making it case insensitive
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Mind your language!")
            return
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

The above code is updated and tested by me it will not have errors.

Comment: No. This will never work, you can't do `list in string`. You'd need to use an `any()` statement to do that, your answer literally raises type errors. `if any(word in message for word in b_words)` is the correct way to do what you're trying here.